# Run time error 1004, Application defined or object defined error in excel vbs

Tags: vbscript

I have written vbscript code to add chart in page 1 of excel for which the source is from other sheet of same excel which name is "CL.1.1" but i am getting the above error can any one help what was wrong in my below code.

```
Sub DispvsTime(Shname)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    noofsheets = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
    If noofsheets > 0 Then
       ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Select
       ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    Sheets("Sheet1").Pictures.Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(1000, 420, 50, 500).Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(Shname).Range("G2:H2001")
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Displacement VS Time"
End Sub
```

here **shname** is name of the sheet where data is picked.

Can any one help me to find out the bug inside the code to get this error ?

Answer (score 0):

If the sheet name is Shname then place it around quotation marks, if it is a variable name, which holds the sheet name, then ignore this post :P

```
Sheets("Shname")
```

Comment: Shname is the parameter of the procedure, so obviously not a literal name.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is really VBScript as you say, and not VBA as it looks like, then there are several issues:

- Unlike VBA you cannot use objects like `ActiveSheet` or `ActiveChart` directly in VBScript. You need a reference to these objects, usually the application object:

  ```
  Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  xl.ActiveSheet.Name = "foo"
  ```
- VBScript doesn't know about Excel/Office constants like `xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers` or `msoElementChartTitleAboveChart`, so you have to either use literal values or define those constants yourself:

  ```
  Const xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers = 73
  ```
- You can't use named arguments like `Source:=...` in VBScript:

  ```
  xl.ActiveChart.SetSourceData xl.Sheets(Shname).Range("G2:H2001")
  ```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vbscript/info) for a more detailed explanation of the differences between VBA and VBScript.